# Why do I get a 10 minute countdown when going offline?

Tags: xbox-360

Recently I have been encountering an odd problem when playing Far Cry Instincts Predator.  When my internet connection drops the Xbox 360 will give me a 10 minute countdown.  Every minute a message will display stating I must restore the connection within x minutes or will be automatically signed out.  Sure enough, after 10 minutes I am signed out.

The game is a games on demand title that I bought a while back.  I am playing the single player campaign.  There is no coop or other means to play the campaign online (but it does have a multiplayer mode).  It seems to only occur on this game (I have tried Call of Duty Ghosts via disk and a couple of other arcade titles).  It doesn't occur on Dirt 3 (games on demand).  It doesn't occur when I am on the dashboard (i.e. not in any game).

I have bought all my games on demand games on the same profile and console.

I can replicate the problem by switching off my router mid-game.

I tried googling the problem but was unable to find anything useful.  Results are showing general connection issues, such as common problems when the internet connection drops every few minutes.

Does anyone know why this is occurring?  Does it occur on other games?

Answer (score 2):

This message only applies to games on demand. You must be signed in to Xbox Live to be able to play these games. If you get disconnected from the internet, like you did when you turned off your router, then this countdown is displayed and you will be signed out of Xbox Live.

It is looking for a license for the game, since you're disconnected from the internet it can't find the license and therefore signs you out.

Edit: I actually did a quick Google search for, "Xbox 10 minutes remaining" and I received a ton of results to talk about this problem being for on demand games.

Comment: Yes, I can see these results, thanks.  I think I had "offline" in the string of words so must have been throwing me towards the wrong results. It is strange that this doesn't occur on Dirt 3, which is games on demand, and that I purchased both games on this same xbox. I will try the license transfer option to see if that fixes things.

Comment: @CamelCase Do you have a disc for Dirt 3 or played it previously?

Comment: I played the game on disc a few years ago when I borrowed it from a friend.  I no longer have the disc, only the games on demand which I subsequently picked up myself.

Comment: @CamelCase Ah, that may be why it doesn't happen on Dirt 3 then. I _think_ there is some type of cache from when the disc ran on your system. So it thinks there is a license for the game on your system. Don't quote me on that though.

Comment: Possibly the online pass, I am pretty sure I redeemed it as the owner said they won't play online.  Back to the game at hand, strange that the console cannot find the license.  I may try redownloading it before doing the license transfer to see if that fixes it.  Pretty sure the license transfer will fix it (although I cannot explain why Xbox have assigned it to another console, maybe more likely that it isn't assigned to any console?).

Comment: I found out the problem. I purchased via the website, so it went to my original xbox (died a long time ago) in terms of the license. I downloaded on my new xbox but you need to do the license transfer to reassign any old DRM configs.

Comment: For Games on Demand games only, you need to be signed into Xbox Live only when playing a game assigned to a different console.  This rule only applies for owners of the game.  If you don't own the game I am not too sure (possibly does the same thing).  Digging into plenty of forums I found it is possibly due to a previously well known pirating method.

Comment: People were copying a game to an image file, then applying some very simple tools to repackage the image as a Games on Demand title.  The Xbox had an update to force DRM checking to prevent people playing such games offline (and I presume to enforce bans when online, or at least do some integrity checking).  Most info I found is speculation, but some stories seemed credible.